# Text in here doc is not showing in multi line

Tags: php

I am using the following heredoc code to output multi line code. But, all the code is showed in single line. I couldn't understand the reason

```
<?php
$var= <<<_JES
--> This is line1,
--> This is line2,
--> This is line3.
_JES;
echo $var;
```

It's output is

```
--> This is line1, --> This is line2, --> This is line3.
```

Could anybody help me with this.

Comment: your code is working fine ,please check here http://codepad.org/QPwpszzF

Comment: The code does create line breaks. HOWEVER, html does not print out new lines automatically unless you enclose it within `<pre>` or add `<br>` tags.

Comment: `echo '<pre>' . $var . '</pre>'`

Comment: add the `<pre>` `</pre>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are viewing the output in a browser. Browsers ignore normal new lines.

In order for the browser to show the lines on new lines you have to tell it, using the HTML `<br>` tag, to put new lines there.

```
$var = <<<JES
--> This is line1,<br>
--> This is line2,<br>
--> This is line3.
JES;
echo $var;
```

If you want the text to be shown as-is then you can also use the `<pre>` tag:

```
$var = <<<JES
<pre>
--> This is line1,
--> This is line2,
--> This is line3.
</pre>
JES;
echo $var;
```

That will show the text exactly like it is outputted (much like the code in this answer). The `<pre>` tag will put a horizontal scroll bar on the page, however, if the text is longer than the screen is wide (unless changed using CSS). The tag is usually used for showing stuff like code or poetry (stuff that has to be formatted exactly as the author intended).

Comment: Yes, I am viewing this in a browser. Doesn't it automatically output the text in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

use echo br/ in <> ;  at each place where you want a new line.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But, it beats the purpose of heredoc.